# Why the list is refreshed when I update the state with Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I'm using Riverpod as a beginner and I want to implements pagination in my page.

When I scroll down, I'm doing a new API call to fetch next items, but at the same moment, I'm back at the top of my content. The items are well loaded, so I need to scroll again to see new items.

**UPDATED**
Here is my page code :

```dart
import 'package:auto_route/annotations.dart';
import 'package:des_cartes/src/core/logger/log_service.dart';
import 'package:des_cartes/src/features/boardgames/presentation/manager/boardgames.provider.dart';
import 'package:des_cartes/src/features/boardgames/presentation/widgets/boardgame_tile.widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

@RoutePage(name: 'BoardgamesPage')
class BoardgamesPage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const BoardgamesPage({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState createState() => _BoardgamesPageState();
}

class _BoardgamesPageState extends ConsumerState<BoardgamesPage> {
  late ScrollController scrollController;
  late GlobalKey scrollKey;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    scrollController = ScrollController();
    scrollKey = GlobalKey();

    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.atEdge) {
        if (scrollController.position.pixels != 0) {
          ref.read(pageProvider.notifier).update((state) => state = state + 1);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final boardgames = ref.watch(boardgamesListNotifierProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
            child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Image.asset(
            "assets/logo_title_cropped.png",
            height: 45,
          ),
        )),
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(171, 237, 216, 1.0),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Search',
            ),
            onChanged: (value) {
              ref
                  .read(searchGameProvider.notifier)
                  .update((state) => state = value);
            },
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              key: scrollKey,
              controller: scrollController,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      child: boardgames.when(
                          data: (boardgames) => Center(
                                child: Wrap(
                                    spacing: 10,
                                    runSpacing: 10,
                                    children: boardgames
                                        .map((boardgame) =>
                                            BoardgameTile(boardgame: boardgame))
                                        .toList()),
                              ),
                          error: (err, _) => Text("error: $err"),
                          loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator()),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my providers :

```dart
import 'package:des_cartes/src/core/logger/log_service.dart';
import 'package:des_cartes/src/features/boardgames/data/data_sources/boardgames.datasource.dart';
import 'package:des_cartes/src/features/boardgames/data/repositories/boardgames.repository.dart';
import 'package:des_cartes/src/features/boardgames/domain/entities/boardgame.dart';
import 'package:des_cartes/src/features/boardgames/domain/entities/boardgame.sort_filter_config.dart';
import 'package:des_cartes/src/features/boardgames/domain/repositories/boardgames.repository.dart';
import 'package:des_cartes/src/features/boardgames/domain/use_cases/get_boardgames.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';

part 'boardgames.provider.g.dart';

@riverpod
BoardgamesDatasource boardgameDatasource(BoardgameDatasourceRef ref) =>
    BoardgamesDatasource();

@riverpod
BoardgamesRepository boardgamesRepository(BoardgamesRepositoryRef ref) =>
    BoardgamesRepositoryImpl(
        datasource: ref.watch(boardgameDatasourceProvider));

@riverpod
class BoardgamesListNotifier extends _$BoardgamesListNotifier {
  @override
  Future<List<Boardgame>> build() async {
    return fetchBoardgames();
  }

  Future<List<Boardgame>> fetchBoardgames() async {
    final searchGame = ref.watch(searchGameProvider);
    final page = ref.watch(pageProvider);

    final config = BoardgameSortFilterConfig(
        filter: searchGame,
        limit: 10,
        page: page,
        type: BoardgameType.boardgameexpansion);

    final boardgamesRepository = ref.read(boardgamesRepositoryProvider);
    final boardgames = await GetBoardgames(boardgamesRepository)(config);

    return boardgames.fold((failure) => [], (boardgames) {
      return [...?state.value, ...boardgames];
    });
  }
}

final searchGameProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) => '');
final pageProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) => 1);
```

I want to stay at the bottom of my page, to see new items loaded !
I think I'm not using the correct things, please let me know !

## Update thanks to @Ruble

It's better !
I have a strange behavior, here is a video link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1am7t4Cu9Tz8J23sggx7fKL3sBFRO7hvF/view?usp=sharing

- When I swipe slowly, while letting the finger on the screen, I can see new items, but it blinks (First part of the video)
- When I swipe hard , I can see my scrollview scroll to top (Second part of the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new list instead of expanding an existing one:

```dart
return boardgames.fold((failure) => [], (boardgames) {
      return [...?state.value, ...boardgames];
    });
```

Also, you should not create controllers, global keys, or attach listeners in the `build` method. `build` is called many times and each time a listener will be attached, and old controllers will not be properly disposed of. Instead, use `ConsumerStatefulWidget` and in `initState` initialize your data correctly (and attach listeners).

Comment: Thanks for your hints, it solves a problem, but another one appears, you can see it i my edited question

Comment: The thing is that when you watch to the widget
using `ref.watch(boardgamesListNotifierProvider)`, then you do this for the entire `_BoardgamesPageState` widget. Try using `Consumer` and inject it where the first use of `boardgames` occurs. This will allow you to rebuild only the desired part of the tree, and not the entire `Scaffold`. Next, keep in mind that with this architecture you will notice updates and a `CircularProgressIndicator` widget. Probably some flag in `when` might help you at this stage.

Comment: I just try the `Consumer`, but nothing changes.  For the loading, I think that's the problem. Each time I fetch the new page, the `loading` part of the `when` is executing (I put a log), so that's why it blink ! I will continue my researches for that

Comment: That's right, using `Consumer` only reduces the rebuilds of the data-dependent widget tree. The `skipLoadingOnReload` flag in `when` may change the behavior a bit, because the widget will only be rebuilt when new data arrives.

Comment: It works like a charm ! But I want to display my `CircularProgressIndicator` at the bottom of the list, is it possible to do it easily ?

Comment: Yes, put a `CircularProgressIndicator` widget in your `Column` in the list of children at the end if the state is in the process of loading `AsyncValue.isLoading`.

Comment: You're the best ! That's why I needed. Thanks !